# connecting Bigquery to Power BI Desktop (Error : DNS resolution failed)

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi

I'm trying to connect Google BigQuery with PowerBI using a built-in connector for that. When I try to load a chosen table, I get an error:

Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][BigQuery] (310) Storage API Error: DNS resolution failed. '.

I have the highest possible permissions as a user, so that's probably not the case. Any ideas?